# Why does React player subtitle does not work?

Tags: reactjs

Based on react player instructions here is my code:

```
<ReactPlayer
  url={videos / mymovie.mkv}
  playing={true}
  width="100%"
  height="65%"
  controls={true}
  config={{
    file: {
      tracks: [
        {
          kind: "subtitles",
          src: "subs/mymovie.srt",
          srcLang: "en",
          default: true
        }
      ]
    }
  }}
/>;
```

but it does not show anything. I put both videos and subs in public folder and the movie plays but without subtitle.

Comment: What versions of react and react player are you using?

Comment: `videos/mymovie.mkv` is interpreted as JavaScript expression, not as a string value containing a file path.

Comment: Did  the answers solve your problem?

Answer (score 2):

Try this solution it worked for me, (use absolute path).
You need to add additional `import` with path to your subtitles file.Also change `url` to `string` : `url="videos/mymovie.mkv"`

```
import videoSubtitles from 'subs/mymovie.srt';
```

---

In `config` change `src: videoSubtitles`, Like this =>

Example code snippet:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactPlayer from 'react-player'
import videoSubtitles from 'subs/mymovie.srt';

<ReactPlayer
  url="videos/mymovie.mkv"
  playing={true}
  width="100%"
  height="65%"
  controls={true}
  config={{
    file: {
      tracks: [
        {
          kind: "subtitles",
          src: videoSubtitles,
          srcLang: "en",
          default: true
        }
      ]
    }
  }}
/>;
```

Comment: Maybe explain what you changed?

Comment: @FelixKling Thx for good suggestion ;-) It's done ! Best regards ! ;-)

Comment: what if i want to use dynamic path?

Comment: I think it's a good topic, an idea for a separate question ;-) In this case I did my best FY ;-)